# jquery mobile responsive images template

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design

First, sorry becouse I'm just starting with jquery mobile and responsive design.

I'm trying to build a template with jquery mobile for create an mobile app.

The problem is with the mobile and tablets sizes.

My tests don't appear like I want. I want to build something like shows in the image.

http://aprendeinformaticaconmigo.com/images/resposive_app_template.png

Can anyone tell me how do this for different mobile and tablet sizes?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Use grids instead of tables. Check jquery mobile grid system http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/grids/ or use any 3rd party plugin http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-mobile-960/

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rnErL/

Very little code for it

CSS:

```
.box {
    max-width:500px;
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.bottom-left, .bottom-right {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute; 
    background-color:green;
}

.bottom-left {
    bottom:5px;
}

.bottom-right {
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="bottom-left"></div>
<div class="bottom-right"></div>
```